# How to disable/delete a Harvest account?

Tags: account-management, harvest

How can I delete or deactivate a [Harvest](http://www.getharvest.com/) account?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. When logged in, look to the upper right corner, to the icon/avatar, and click the down arrow.

   [image: down from the upper right top corner]
2. Select **Account Settings**

   You'll come to a page entitled, *Account Settings*. The first section will be *Billing Information*.
3. Click on **Close Account**
4. You will see a page entitled, *Hold or Remove Account*.

   There's a short survey/feedback for you to fill out but from there you can suspend if you fill out the *Put Account on Hold* section.

   To delete or close out your account, just use the *Permanently Remove Account* section and you're done.

Download your data before you do as that is toast when you delete your account.